# call_user_func_array with variable name

Tags: php, function, object

suppose I need to use a variable's name as the function name of [`call_user_func_array()`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/call_user_func_array)

eg.

```
$j = new SomeObject();
```

and I'm trying to call `$j->funcme();`

```
call_user_func_array('$j->funcme()',$args);
```

returns the not found or invalid function name error

what should I do to rectify this?

Comment: Have you checked out the manual of [`call_user_func_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php)? The answer to your question is right in the first example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use it with an array for the *Callback*:

```
call_user_func_array(array($j, 'funcme'), $args);
```

See: [`call_user_func_array`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/call_user_func_array)